# Initialising subcomponents of a GUI form

Tags: codenameone

I am facing a complication in initializing subcomponents of a `GUIBuilder` Form

For example for a GUI form called "Profile"  with a `TextArea` Field named  "deal".
Text that should be displayed in this text field is retrieved from a remote site in a way of making it not to be dynamic.
Therefore is there a way in which I can initialize the `TextArea` value .

```
eg text retrieved from server = "Hello CodenameOne Developers"
```

How then I initialize this text into the `TextArea` field other than the normal way when doing it from code which is :

```
String a= "Hello CodenameOne Developers";
TextArea deal= new TextArea(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `findDeal(c).setText(a)`.

Notice that we are in a migration period to a new GUI builder which uses a more traditional [Form based architecture](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-gui-builder.html).